# What happens when you Imbue arrow with sleep?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, prestige-class

So if you go through the Arcane Archer prestige class at level 2 of arcane archer you can imbue your arrows with spells which basically allows you to give your choice of spell ... really whatever range you want it to have especially if your in a combat situation, but that's not the question at hand here

Based off the wording of sleep if a creature is wounded after having sleep /deep slumber cast on them they wake up. So if you hit someone with an arrow imbued with such a spell and the person you hit has less hit die then sleep can make unconscious - wouldn't the fact you hit them with the arrow cause them to instantly wake up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spell takes effect when the target is hit by the arrow. Thus, the sleep is after the damage not before.

Note: according to d20 SRD, Imbue Arrow only allows an Area of Effect spell which will be centered on where the arrow lands.

Comment: Also, you could always simply aim at a square rather than a specific target due to the AoE clause.

Comment: @nijineko - yes, but OP specifically asked about the damage of being hit.